# How to fix incompatible matrix dimensions using mvJointModelBayes()?

Tags: r

I'm trying to fit a joint model of longitudinal and time-to-event data using the JMbayes package, to predict risk of cardiac arrest as more symptom data becomes available over time. To start, I am fitting a univariate model, but I aim to incorporate a number of longitudinal outcomes once I have the code running, which is why I'm using the mvJointModelBayes() function.

However, when I run I try to run the function I come across the error below.

*Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "addition: incompatible matrix dimensions: 500x1 and 3000x1"*

I have used the same code as provided in the mvJMBayes vignette using pbc2 data, adapted to my dataset, but keep encountering the error. I can't find any obvious way in which my dataframes differ to the pbc2 dataset to be causing the error.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(JMbayes)
library(lattice)
library(MASS)

# SIMULATE DATA AND SHAPE FOR MODELLING -------------------

id            <- 1:500
gender        <- sample(c('Male','Female'), 500, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.51, 0.49))
status        <- sample(c(0,1), 500, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.9, 0.1))
survival_days <- rnorm(500)

angina1 <- sample(c(0,1), 500, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.9, 0.1))
angina2 <- sample(c(0,1), 500, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.8, 0.2))
angina3 <- sample(c(0,1), 500, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7, 0.3))

# Wide format for survival modelling. Single row per patient.
data_wide <- as.data.frame(
  cbind(id, gender, status, survival_days, angina1, angina2, angina3))

# Recode factor levels
data_wide$survival_days<- as.numeric(data_wide$survival_days)
data_wide$status       <- as.numeric(data_wide$status)

# Long format for longitudinal modelling. 
data_long <- data_wide %>% gather(angina1:angina3, key = "timepoint", value = "angina")
data_long$timepoint <- str_replace(data_long$timepoint,"angina","")
data_long <- data_long %>% mutate(angina = as.factor(angina), timepoint = as.numeric(timepoint))

# MODELLING ---------------------------------------------------

set.seed(123)
mixed_model_fit <- mvglmer(list(angina ~ timepoint + (timepoint | id)), data = data_long, families = list(binomial))
cox_fit <- coxph(Surv(survival_days, status) ~ gender, data = data_wide, model = TRUE)
JMFit <- mvJointModelBayes(mixed_model_fit, cox_fit, timeVar = "timepoint")
```

The last part of the code above returns:

*Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "addition: incompatible matrix dimensions: 500x1 and 3000x1"*

Is anybody able to shed light on how to fix this error?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to add more library call(s) to make this reproducible. It sounds like a great question, though. I cannot tell whether just adding `library(maggitr)` would be enough, or do you need to also load`dplyr` or will it require the entire `tidyverse` suite. (I can observe that installing `JMbayes` takes a long time and will require extra system level packages  if it's not already in place.)

Comment: I've now tried this twice, once on an Rstudio session and once in a Terminal session and both times I simply see the session hanging. This has been reproted as an issue in another Linux user's experience: https://github.com/drizopoulos/JMbayes/issues/7 but it wasn't able to be reproduced by the package maintainer. I see no ongoing activity that I recognize as R using the htop process monitor. The second time I loaded tidyverse first and then the packages listed above with no difference in the behavior.

Comment: Looks like the issue that I referenced has been closed. There is an open message that has a different error related to matrix errors with the pbc2 dataset: https://github.com/drizopoulos/JMbayes/issues/8

Comment: Thanks @42-, I was missing the library(tidyverse) call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it works if `id` is a numeric variable instead of a factor and if `id` occurs in the same order in both data sets. Running the following code before model fitting solves the issue:

```
data_long <- data_long %>% 
  mutate(id = as.numeric(id)) %>% 
  arrange(id)

data_wide <- data_wide %>% 
  mutate(id = as.numeric(id)) %>% 
  arrange(id)
```